# Oracle Join precedence

Tags: join

When joining multiple tables, involving all join types (inner, left,cross, full etc), is there any specific order in which joins are evaluated, like we have BODMAS in Mathematics or it always reads from left to right in the order we specified. 
I don't have the exact SQL but here is a sample SQL:

```
Select * from 
A,
B 
LEFT JOIN 
C
ON B.ID = C.ID,
D
FULL JOIN 
E
ON 
D.ID = E.ID;
```

Will it be like A cross joining with B and the result Left joining with C and so on..? 
OR 
A cross joining with the Left join of B and C..

Comment: `from a,b left join` is wrong. Do **not** mix the old, outdated implicit joins (using comma in the `from` clause` and the explicit `JOIN`  operator.

Comment: I do not use it but i got similar query from someone to understandand debug